# Xamarin Android app crashing with "Intent must include an explicit package name to build an android-app"

Tags: android-intent, xamarin, crash, xamarin.android

My `Xamarin Android` app needs to pop up the gallery so that the user can select an existing photo and in this scenario I again save the URI of the selected image.

On a Galaxy S5 owned by on of my test users, it is crashing every single time. Yet it works fine on my cheaper/older Huawei test phone.

I am using Azure Mobile Center for crash reporting and I'm seeing this in my error logs. When debugging live from the Galaxy S5 I also see this error thrown directly from within Visual Studio...

> Intent must include an explicit package name to build an android-app:
>   Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/4238 flg=0x1
>   VirtualScreenParam=Params{mDisplayId=-1, null, mFlags=0x00000000)}
>   (has extras) }

This is the method where I'm creating the intent for selecting from gallery:

```
    public void HandleRecord(object sender, EventArgs ea)
    {
        ...
                //Choose from gallery
                else if (args.Which == 1)
                {
                    var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick);
                    intent.SetType("image/*");
                    this.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_FILE);
                }
        }
    }
```

The code is crashing on this exact line in my OnActivityResult method...

```
 if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            {
                ImageUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(data.ToUri(IntentUriType.AndroidAppScheme));
```

Comment: Which API versions are crashing? Are they all the same? (i.e. API 21?)

Comment: From what I can see in Azure Mobile Center, the main device is "SM-G930F" (Galaxy S7?) so I think it's really new i.e. version 23?

Comment: App crashing after taking photo or selecting photo? Also are you getting same error each time app crash?

Comment: Have you tried Intent.ActionGetContent instead of Intent.ActionPick?

Comment: Check if there is a camera app available to handle this intent i.e. do intent.ResolveActivity(packageManager) != null if not then I recommend preinstalling a good camera app to handle such an intent like opencamera

Comment: Thanks guys. @StevenMarkFord - silly question, but doesn't Android come with a basic enough camera app that should work reliably? It actually successfully pops up and will take a photo, but then the app just completely closes. I.e. the camera intent doesn't *always* return back to the app.

Comment: @PravinD I did try Intent.ActionGetContent - I noticed it popped up with a lot more "app" options including the file manager etc. I.e. over and above simply displaying the Gallery and Photos that ActionPick provides. So it's not as clean/tidy in terms of user experience in that way. But I still receive errors sometimes even after trying to take a new photo - which is the other intent etc.

Comment: @PravinD This is the only error coming into my crash reporting platform. Also when I'm debugging from within Visual Studio 2015 and the app crashes, I actually see no errors thrown in my code. It's something unhappy inside of Android/native I think relating to the way I may have called or setup the intent. Where as, I've had other bugs in my code that were easy to fix because VS was debugging and I could easily see the offending line in code etc. But my own code doesn't seem to crash here, it's something in Android/Java..

Comment: @StevenMarkFord How does this look?

                            var intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
                            if (intent.ResolveActivity(Forms.Context.PackageManager) != null)
                            { // existing intent code here...
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                this.Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "No camera app available!", ToastLength.Short).Show());
                            }

Comment: In native android this works great, so I think it is something wrong in a bridge between xamarin android and native android I suggest you to use example code given in xamarin android developer site.

Comment: @Aaron looks good. I have had default camera apps do this before. Open Camera has always worked as expected, give it a try and see if you get results.

Comment: Thanks @StevenMarkFord - looks like I'm still seeing some bad instability around this code relating to the native camera intent stuff.. Steven would you recommend possibly packaging in some other kind of third party camera component that may be more reliable? Is this common practise rather than relying on the default native one?

Comment: Ok some further info. Today I debugged on a user's real Galaxy S5 device. This error is actually related to the Select Existing Image functionality, not the camera taking a photo. So it's this code:
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick);                    intent.SetType("image/*");
this.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_FILE);

Then it IS firing my OnActivityResult and crashing on this exact line of code, trying to get a Uri from the intent:
ImageUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(data.ToUri(IntentUriType.AndroidAppScheme));

Comment: Ok guys after some key discoveries today debugging, I've completely updated/refined the question to be much more specific now. Hopefully we are getting close..!

Comment: Ok even further, I've now narrowed this crash down further to API version 23+. I setup another new emulator which runs this same API version as the Galaxy S5 phone that was having issues and now I'm throwing the same error from within Visual Studio. Got to be close now to solving this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my goodness, found it. On API 23+ I had to add this line of code when declaring the intent for the "select an image from gallery" option:

```
intent.SetPackage("com.android.gallery");
```

So the overall code became:

```
                    var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent );
                    intent.SetType("image/*");
                    intent.SetPackage("com.android.gallery");
                    this.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_FILE);
```

I'll never understand why I need to do this after already declaring the Intent.ActionPick type, but hey it works and error is no longer thrown.

Comment: Then when running this code back on an older KitKat device, I received a permissions error. So worked out that Intent.ActionPick should instead be Intent.ActionGetContent - now permissions issue resolved and also original issue resolved!!